# In Python, how to supply the command line arguments in interactive mode

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I want to run a software in interactive mode. In the manual it says the usage

python experiment.py --config config.yaml --out result/

The question is, how can I supply the command line arguments to experiment.py in interactive mode?

Comment: Take a look at the `experiment.py` file and see how its `main` function calls the other functions defined in `experiment.py`, and that will show you how you can call them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The commandline arguments that e.g. `optparse` and `argparse` uses are taken by default from `sys.argv` element 1 and up. You can always do:

```
import sys
sys.argv[1:] = ['--config', 'config.yaml', '--out', 'result/']
```

Although e.g. in `argparse` you can provide the arguments explicitly to `.parse_args()` as well and then [that method will not inspect `sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you need something like this:

```
while True:
    query = raw_input("> ")
    if query == "exit":
        break
    # do something useful
```